# Bounded sequence for strictly positive numbers question

Tags: real-analysis

I don't understand how to get to the part underlined in red.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The underlined red part is exactly using the assumption that $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n+1/a_n = \infty$

Answer (score 0):

Because $\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)=+\infty$, by definition: for any $M_2>0$ we can find $N\in \mathbb{N}_+$ such that for all $n>N$ we have that $\left(a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\right)>M_2$. Now this happens exactly for $M_2=\left(\frac{1}{\varepsilon}\right)+M$, where $\varepsilon$ and $M$ have already been chosen in a favorable way to finish the proof.

Answer (score 0):

Note that $a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\rightarrow \infty$ so it gets arbitrarily large that is there is some $N$ such that for $n>N$:

$a_n+\frac{1}{a_n}\rightarrow \geq C$ for some large $C$. Now,that means, you can write
$C=\frac{1}{\epsilon}+M$ where $\epsilon$ is small.

Answer (score 0):

It is just the definition of limit $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} = +\infty$.

The definition says that for every $\delta > 0$ there exist $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that

$$n \ge N \implies a_n + \frac{1}{a_n} \ge \delta$$

They just took $\delta = M + \frac1\varepsilon$ for convenience.

---

You can also solve it without $\varepsilon$:

We have $a^2 + 1 \le M^2 + 1$ so:

$$0 \le a_n \le a_n \cdot \frac{M^2+1}{a^2+1} = (M^2+1)\cdot\frac{1}{a_n + \frac{1}{a_n}} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0$$

Therefore, the squeeze theorem yields $\lim_{n\to\infty} a_n = 0$